# How to pick right value of capacitor while switching DC source

Tags: capacitor, dc

I have two loads consuming 0.5A,12V and 0.6A,5V. Load demanding 12v is powered through boost converter and 5v Dc source. And load demanding 5v is connected directly to 5v dc source. By design, whenever dc power source switch goes from one source to another there is a black out for 1second.

I read somewhere a capacitor can solve my problem. Can someone please help me calculate a capacitor value for above load for a second?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A capacitor may work but it has to have a large value. Your 12 volt boost converter supplying 0.5 amps may be taking something like 1.5 amps from your 5 volt power rail. Your 5 volt load is taking 0.6 amps. If I have misinterpreted your detail please say!

That's 2.1 amps in total.

It then boils down to how much droop or voltage sag you can permit on the 5 volt rail during the 1 second blackout. If you can permit the 5 volts to sag down to 4.5 volts then you can figure out how much capacitance you need using the capacitor formula: -

$$I = C\cdot\dfrac{dv}{dt}$$

So, if dv/dt is 0.5 volts per second and I = 2.1 amps, capacitance needs to be greater than 4.2 farads. Looks like you might need a supercap rated at 5 volts. Get one with the lowest ESR you can find or, simulate to see by how much ESR affects the droop.

Comment: What if I use a second one cap after boost convertor?

Comment: @ShivendraMishra that is certainly an option AND, if you can somehow disable the boost converter during the blackout period, the capacitance on the output should hold up the 12 volt load without any surge of current being taken from the "blacked out" input voltage. That might be worth exploring if what you really need is to maintain 5 volts to the 5 volt load.

Answer (score 3):

To put the answer by Andy aka another way, the capacitor can be calculated fairly simply, provided that the maximum voltage sag is fairly small.

Decide what voltage sag is acceptable when running on capacitor alone.  If the answer is "zero", then a capacitor alone won't help you.

The capacitor you need, in Farads, is

```
current x time / voltage_sag
```

So if you need 2.1A for 1 second, and a sag of 0.5V is acceptable, then you need

```
2.1 x 1 / 0.5 = 4.2F
```

Comment: Will there be any change in cap size if I decide to use a second one after boost converter?

Comment: @ShivendraMishra If you put a capacitor after the boost converter, then the boost converter will try to keep it charged to 12V. So the capacitor won't end up doing much.  To do anything useful, you would have to switch off the boost converter, so as to draw down the 12V capacitor.